# Getting an InvalidRequest error with Azure SSO - any advice for diagnosing the issue?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Azure SSO - Response status code does not indicate success: 426 (InvalidRequest).
Server Error in '/azuressotest' Application.
Response status code does not indicate success: 426 (InvalidRequest).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 426 (InvalidRequest).
Azure SSO,OpenId, Authentication,Account sign, MS login
Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 426 (InvalidRequest).]
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() +121834
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__0.MoveNext() +399

[IOException: Unable to get document from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/******5/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=****]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__0.MoveNext() +725
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__1.MoveNext() +414
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__3.MoveNext() +908

[InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/1426******/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=d91b1af3*****.]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__3.MoveNext() +1255
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.d__c.MoveNext() +522
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__8.MoveNext() +376
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__5.MoveNext() +215
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +968
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +197
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +768
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +197
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext() +184
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +117
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +209
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +156

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3930.0

additionally, this same solution works well for one client (different Windows server - 2012)

have above error for all other clients (Windows Server 2019)

Not sure it's network issue or Windows server security setting issue

Can anybody give suggestion what change is required

thank you so much

additionally, this same solution works well for one client (different Windows server - 2012)

have above error for all other clients (Windows Server 2019)

Not sure it's network issue or Windows server security setting issue

Can anybody give suggestion what change is required

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out solution
I explicitly only allowing TLS1.2 for MS login
so that Web server don't have to change their security setting as long as it has TLS1.2 enable on their Windows Servers